# Save video frames as images c# , Emgu cv

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am trying to save videos frames to a folder but it's not working. I am using emgu cv image processing library for this project.

```
public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Mat mat = new Mat();

    capture.Retrieve(mat);

    FrameRate = capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
    Thread.Sleep((int)(1000.0 / FrameRate));          

    imageBox1.Image = mat;

    if (mat != null)
    {
        mat.Save(@"C:\Desktop\images");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("null image");
    }

    //GetVideoFrames1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EmguCV, I highly recommend using Emgu's own VideoWriter (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/3fb90645-ecc4-0c4e-b238-6d0ca38f4ebc.htm), this allows you to create a video file and continuously write to it when you receive a new Mat, ie

```
VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter(filePath + @"\" + fileName + ".avi", yourCodec, fps, size, true);
for(;;)
{
    Mat image = getNextFrame();
    writer.Write(frame);
}
```

Comment: i am actually new to image processing and Emgu cv i am trying to save images of a video to a database . can you give some guidence to my problem

Comment: Hi, that's not a problem! This would write the frames to a .avi video file. Look at the link I attached, it provides information on how it works.